# Sorting Into segements in Notepadd++ (Or Excel)

Tags: excel, sorting, notepad++

I have a list of keys with the names of the product they activate associated with them. I have multiple keys of the same product and multiple products. The list might look like this:

```
1234567    Adobe
7654321    Adobe
1237731    Adobe
2374792    MS Office
1231031    MS Office
1231312    MS Office
1237131    IntelliJ
1238981    IntelliJ
3495729    IntelliJ
```

How would I go about sorting this in Notepadd++ (Or Excel) so the results are:

```
1234567    Adobe
2374792    MS Office
1237131    IntelliJ

7654321    Adobe
1231031    MS Office
1238981    IntelliJ

1237731    Adobe
1231312    MS Office
3495729    IntelliJ
```

Comment: What are the sorting rules? I don't see anyone in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `1234567` is in A2 in say C2 and copied down to one 'set' of blank rows:

```
 =MOD(ROW()-2,3)
```

Where a 'set' is one of each product. Then sort all on ColumnC Smallest to Largest (with header row).